# Merge multiple lines of table with same name

Tags: bash

I have a tab delimited table which I want to change the format of as shown below.

Initially the file was like this

```
 Species    Column1    Column2    Column3
A           3                   
B           1
C           7                        
D           1                        
A                      8            
D                      4             
B                      2             
C                      5             
A                                9
```

What I want is:

```
 Species    Column1    Column2    Column3
A           3          8          9 
B           1          2
C           7          5              
D           1          4
```

Currently I have this:

```
 Species    Column1    Column2    Column3
A           3
A                      8
A                                 9
B           1          
B                      2
C           7   
C                      5       
D           1                       
D                      4
```

I used the sort function to get the bottom table but am unsure of how to then combine the rows together. Anyone know how to?

Answer (score 0):

use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cols=4
nums=$(seq $cols)
files=$(printf "f%s " $nums)

for i in $nums
do
  if [ $i = 1 ]; then
    tail -n +2 $1 | cut -f"$i" | grep '^.' | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u > f"$i"
  else
    tail -n +2 $1 | cut -f"$i" | grep '^.' | cut -d' ' -f1 > f"$i"
  fi
done
head -n1 $1
paste $files
rm -rf $files
```

output is :

```
$ ./script file 
Species Column1 Column2 Column3
A   3   8   9
B   1   4   
C   7   2   
D   1   5
```

Comment: This solution seemed to work fine with the example data but when used on a sample with 13 columns ( I altered the cols = 4 part) and around 200 rows the output file clumped all the numbers to the top leaving the lower ones without any numbers although they should have. Is there a possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming columns are separated by tabs and there are no headers, here's the script:

```
awk -F "\t" '$2' file.txt | sort  > col2.txt
awk -F "\t" '$3' file.txt | sort  > col3.txt
awk -F "\t" '$4' file.txt | sort  > col4.txt
join -a1 -a2 col2.txt col3.txt | join -a1 -a2 - col4.txt
```